# Button on Slider Not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, carousel

I am creating a website and would like to use this ready made slider on my page. I have added it to my code, however, the left button does not work. The right button works but the hover disappears on mobile view.

I am new to web development and therefore still learning. If someone could help that would be much appreciated. The CodePen for this slider is https://codepen.io/bryan-erwin/pen/dJEYVr

```
<header>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="caption" id="slider-caption">
    <div class="caption-heading">
      <h1>Example</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="caption-subhead"><span></span></div><a class="btn" 
href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="left-col" id="left-col">
    <div id="left-slider"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="slide-up">
      <a id="up_botton" href="#"><</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slide-down">
          <a id="down_button" href="#">></a>
        </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </header>
```

I would like the left button to go to the previous slide and the right button hover to work on all views

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript code is incomplete you are listening to the right side button click event by this code:

```
let down_button = document.getElementById('down_button');

down_button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  clearInterval(autoplay);
  nextSlide();
  autoplay;
});
```

you have to add code for the left side button also like this:

```
let up_button = document.getElementById('up_button');

up_button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  clearInterval(autoplay);
  prevSlide(); // you have to create this function
  autoplay;
});
```

for this, you have to also add an `id="up_button"` to the left side button.

Comment: When i add the up_button event listener in the JS the page only shows the two buttons and removes the content of the slide. You can try editing the codepen with what you've told me to add to see what i mean.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, not sure what i'm doing wrong